# error in running query

Tags: sql, mysql

```
where h.er = select ( p.er from tip p where p.os = 'Android' OR 'iOS' ) AND h.ssn = (select h2.ssn  from persons h2 where h2.ssn like '213%');
```

I am performing this function in mysql. IT is not letting me to do it. An error is coming like check the manual the mysql version cooresponds to. I am using 5.1.5.1 MYsql

Comment: Don't let those IT guys push you around! If you really want to run the query, bring this issue up with someone in management.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the `select` inside the parenthesis as:

```
where h.er = ( select p.er fr...
             ^
```

Comment: it is showing me empty set..1 warning. I have all the data in the files

Comment: its showing the syntax error by saying the syntax is not corresponding to mysql version

Comment: can u give me your email id? I cant post my query here as some body else can copy it from here.Its is a Hw.

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing:

```
where p.os = 'Android' OR 'iOS'
```

With:

```
where p.os = 'Android' OR p.os = 'iOS'
```

Or:

```
where p.os IN ('Android', 'iOS')
```

Comment: thanks, bt it is not working either. I used the last sentence of yours.Are they based on mysql version?